# "Réellement" et "vraiment" dans "Voulez-vous réellement/vraiment vous déconnecter ?"

Tags: usage, synonymes

Sur un site j'ai vu :

> Vous êtes en train de vous déconnecter de BU (Bibliothèque universitaire).
>
> Voulez-vous réellement vous déconnecter ?

Pourquoi *réellement* et non *vraiment* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les deux sont possibles.

Il n'y a pas de différence dans le sens de la question exprimée ici.

**Vraiment** : Est-il vrai que vous souhaitez vous déconnecter ?

**Réellement** : Que vous souhaitiez vous déconnecter n'est pas seulement une hypothèse imaginaire ?

*Vraiment* est plus utilisé que *réellement* de nos jours (bien qu'on voie une petite remontée depuis le début des années 2000), alors que c'est l'inverse en anglais avec lequel *truly* est plus formel et beaucoup plus rare que *really*.

Le petite remontée de *réellement* s'explique peut être par l'influence de l'anglais *really*.

[image]

Comment: Merci ! Quand vraiment et réellement ne sont pas interchangeables ?

Comment: Il est vraiment difficile de trouver des exemples... Parfois *vraiment* sert à intensifier alors que réellement est plus binaire : *Il fait vraiment chaud ici !* est courant , *il fait réellement chaud ici !* est improbable. De même, *je suis vraiment malade* indique que la maladie est plus sérieuse qu'il n'y parait tandis que *je suis réellement malade* signifie qu'on ne feint pas d'être malade.

Comment: Merci encore. NGram (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=réellement%2Cvraiment&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Créellement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvraiment%3B%2Cc0) indique que vraiment est plus souvent rencontré.

Comment: Il faut tempérer ce que j'ai écrit dans le commentaire précédent. *Je suis vraiment malade* peut aussi vouloir dire qu'on ne feint pas la maladie. Tout dépend du contexte, de la tonalité, cependant *réellement* sert rarement à intensifier.

Comment: Your two questions (& that of the OP) seem to have "réellement/vraiment" modifying/(going to the truth of) "souhaiter/vouloir" (i.e., "Do you **really want** to log out?"), but could either/both of those adverbs be used to modify/(get to the extent of)  "déconnecter"? (i.e., "Do you want to **really/completely log out**? If so, be sure to close your browser.") "Vraiment" seems to have a sense of "complètement, définitivement, pour de vrai" that might work to modify "déconnecter" in that way, but I can't find that "complètement" sense in *TLFi*'s entry for "réellement." cc: @Dimitris

Comment: @PapaPoule Yes, that's an alternative way to understand it and like in English, the question asked might be *Voulez-vous vous déconnecter complètement ?* However, I wouldn't rule out *voulez-vous réellement vous déconnecter ? Alors, fermez votre navigateur.* to share the same meaning.

Comment: As-tu déjà essayé de/réussi à faire un _embed_ du _iframe_ directement ?

Comment: @survenant9r7 Ce n'est pas possible : https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238542/182055

Answer (score 4):

Dans ce contexte les deux mots sont synonymes. Il s'agit des sens suivants ;

**réellement** ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9ellement))

> **A 1** [Exprime que le procès n'est pas mimé, simulé]
>
> - À la façon dont s'appliquait la bouche, l'on pouvait se rendre compte du plus ou du moins de ferveur et d'affection des pères et des frères; les uns appuyaient les lèvres, embrassaient réellement (...); d'autres, au contraire, frôlaient seulement, se bornaient à remplir un devoir, sans y attribuer plus d'importance.

**vraiment** ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vraiment))

> **A 3 b** [À propos d'une attitude, d'un comportement] Sans faire semblant, sans que ce soit imité ou simulé.
>
> - Elle vint contempler Michele (...). Il était enfoncé, les yeux bien clos, blanc et les mains presque jointes. Il dormait vraiment.
> - [Dans l'attitude de l'enfant au jeu de cache-cache, signalée par Mme Montessori] il ne s'agit point de trouver le partenaire à un endroit quelconque, mais bien à une place déterminée par avance; si l'adulte se cache vraiment, l'enfant est déçu! On voit bien, en cet exemple, le sens profond de l'ordre pour le jeu enfantin.

Answer (score 2):

Complément à d'excellentes réponses (vu [ici](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/r%C3%A9ellement-vraiment.454194/)) ; il concerne l'usage comparé de « vraiment » et « réellement ».

> Dans la plupart des cas, on peut  utiliser les deux adverbes, sans
>   différence de sens. Aucun n'est formel ou familier. « Réellement » a trois
>   syllabes et un hiatus, alors que « vraiment » n'a que deux syllabes et une
>   prononciation sans obstacles, ce qui explique peut-être pourquoi on a tendance à
>   utiliser « vraiment » plus fréquemment.

Ci-dessous, l'original anglais extrait du site mentionné plus haut

In most cases you can use either, with no difference of meaning. 
None is formal or colloquial.
*Réellement* has 3 syllables and a hiatus, while *vraiment* has only 2 syllables and a smooth flow, which may be why we tend to use *vraiment* more frequently.